# How can I create a 'power options' shortcut on desktop with C# code?

Tags: c#

How can I create a shortcut of power options with C# code?

This is my code:

```
WshShellClass wshShell = new WshShellClass();
IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut MyShortcut;

MyShortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)wshShell.CreateShortcut(@"C:\user\Administrator\power options.lnk");

MyShortcut.TargetPath = ???????;

MyShortcut.IconLocation = Application.StartupPath + ??????;
MyShortcut.Save();
```

Comment: I misread this question and thought you wanted to create a shortcut that unleashed the volatile forces of the universe for your own nefarious purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the answer from Moo-Juice, try the following:

```
        WshShell shell = new WshShell();
        string app = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "powercfg.cpl");
        string linkPath = @"C:\PowerLink.lnk";
        IWshShortcut link = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(linkPath);
        link.TargetPath = app;
        link.IconLocation = string.Format("{0},2", app);
        link.Save();
```

Comment: I asked how to create a --'power options'-- shortcut

Comment: Apologies for mis-reading your question. I've edited my answer to provide the code you need.

Comment: I forgot about the "shortcut on the Desktop" part. Change the linkPath line to: string linkPath = Path.Combine(shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"), "PowerLink.lnk");
That will put the link on the current user's Desktop, or for all users replace "Desktop" with "AllUsersDesktop" in the SpecialFolders method call.

Comment: I need to match icon of power options

Comment: To find the icon you require, manually create a shortcut to the Power Options control panel item. Once created look at the Properties of the link. There is a button "Change Icon", press that and the alternative icons are displayed. Work out the offset of the icon you want (starting from zero) and change the code I gave you to use that number. (I'm using XP so things might be different in Vista or Win7)
I've just had a look in Windows 7 and the icon offset is zero for the standard icon. Change "{0},2" to "{0},0" and you should get the same icon as displayed in the control panel.

Comment: works with link:Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "powercpl.dll");

Answer (score 1):

The items in the control panel are stored in `C:\windows\system32` with a `.cpl` extension.  Therefore your target, for power options, should be:

`C:\windows\system32\powercfg.cpl`

**Note:** Do not use the hard-coded strings I have used here, use `Environment.SystemDirectory` to locate the directory appropriately.

Comment: This will break if the Windows folder is not called "Windows", or in half a dozen other cases (like localization).

Comment: You are of course, correct.  I hammered out the answer a bit fast :)